# Most efficient way to get a single value with EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have been using EF6 for a while and I'm at a point where I need to optimize to the maximum every single query I'm performing to the DB.

There is a point where I simply need to get a `string` based on a `Guid`, which is not precisely a complex query but I wanted to know what would be best practice and why:

a) Find/FindAsync

`string senderName = Context.Senders.Find(senderId).Name;`

b) Where, Select and FirstOrDefault/FirstOrDefaultAsync

```
string senderName = Context.Senders.Where(x => x.Id == senderId)
                            .Select(x => x.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I can't profile the SQL it's performing right now but since `a)` query seems "simpler", `b)` query seems to use defered execution (`IQueryable`) which could be more interesting even combined with `async` execution.

Am I right? What would be the best choice and why?

Comment: Probably the most efficient way would be to _not_ use EF at all, but use something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or plain old ADO.NET.

Comment: (a) will load the entire entity while (b) will only load the name. The generated SQL statement for (b) will probably be the same one would write in Dapper or ADO.NET, ie `SELECT Name from Senders where ID=@id`

Comment: You could change version b) to `Context.Senders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == senderId)?.Name;` which is cleaner

Comment: @Aars93 on the contrary, this loads the *entity* instead of just the name

Comment: @UweKeim I'm actually using Dapper on other classes, but let's suppose it couldn't be use here. Useful comment anyway since it's focusing on performance!

Comment: Why can't you profile? There is tons of info available online on async and it's benefits so I won't get into details about that. No async will not be faster, maybe slower but negligible. Efficient way would be to make sure the table is indexed properly. If still slow, don't use EF and use straight ado.net.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The thing isn't that things aren't actually slow, but I don't want to wait for that for no reason. I know EF it's of course not as fast as using directly ADO.NET but I wanted to keep things "easy" so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments: a) loads the whole entity into memory while b) loads only the name. If you need the name only, then b is the much better choice.

Comment: This is not true. a) Does not ALWAYS load the whole entity into memory. It first checks the memory (context), if found it will not even load and thus save you an entire trip to db server. So it depends on how it is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Using Find is much faster. where the quarry is very simple `select * from t where id=[ID]`
is much cleaner and there wont be any db check etc that happen in EF6 and on the top of that EF wont need to parse the `Linq Where and Select statement`.

And also for those people who hate EF, i have build an ORM library that work like EF and the old ADO.Net. with migration, code to db etc all those are offcourse optional. is 100% faster with test prov please check it [EntityWorker.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityWorker.Core/)

Comment: I don't think that's true. `SELECT * FROM ...` is very often slower than `SELECT singleattr FROM ...`, especially if the table has lots of columns and lots of nvarchar(max)-string columns

Comment: Well you are mostly right, It depends on the context. But its still one row and if he have only 10 cols for example then using Find is more effective where EF wont have to parse the `linq Where and Select statement`